# Highest/lowest value without using aggregate functions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a table named `department`, which has following data

```
DNO DNAME   SALARY
20  EE  30000
10  DoC 50000
30  ITS 20000
```

I want to select employee with maximum and minimum salary WITHOUT using `GROUP` functions or top-n analysis or `NOT EXISTS` command. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For max. salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM department d1
WHERE salary > ALL (SELECT d2.salary
                    FROM department d2
                    WHERE d2.dno <> d1.dno)
```

For min salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM department d1
WHERE salary < ALL (SELECT d2.salary
                    FROM department d2
                    WHERE d2.dno <> d1.dno)
```

Both solutions assume that salary can not be null

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just with joins, if you don't want to use any of the more complex operators.

```
SELECT *
  FROM SO.dbo.MaxNoAgg mna1
LEFT JOIN SO.dbo.MaxNoAgg mna2 ON (mna2.salary > mna1.salary)
WHERE mna2.mna_id IS NULL;
```

That will basically give you the row for which no row with a greater salary exists. Of course, it still gives all the rows with the maximal value (`SELECT DISTINCT mna1.salary`).

Answer (score 0):

```
set nocount on
declare @table table (
    val int
)

insert @table values (17)
insert @table values (31)
insert @table values (8)
insert @table values (79)
insert @table values (25)
insert @table values (13)

select * from @table

select * from @table t where 1 = (select count(distinct val) from @table where t.val >= val)
select * from @table t where 1 = (select count(distinct val) from @table where t.val <= val)
```